# Getting ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in Adapter class

Tags: java, android, kotlin

When I click item I get

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length = 10; index = -1

It's my `onCreateViewHolder` method, when i click item, i want to open DetailActivity and send data with intent

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.alphabet_item, parent, false)
    val holder = ViewHolder(view)
    view.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(parent.context, ItemAlphabetDetailActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("NAME", alphabets[holder.position].context)/*
        intent.putExtra("CONTEXT", alphabets[holder.adapterPosition].context)
        intent.putExtra("IMAGE", alphabets[holder.adapterPosition].image)
        intent.putExtra("SOUND", alphabets[holder.adapterPosition].sound)*/
        parent.context.startActivity(intent)
    }
    return ViewHolder(view)
}
```

It is my class `ItemAlphabetAdapter`

```
class ItemAlphabetAdapter(
private val alphabets: ArrayList<ItemAlphabet>
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemAlphabetAdapter.ViewHolder>() {


override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.alphabet_item, parent, false)
    val holder = ViewHolder(view)
    view.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(parent.context, ItemAlphabetDetailActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("NAME", alphabets[holder.position].context)/*
        intent.putExtra("CONTEXT", alphabets[holder.adapterPosition].context)
        intent.putExtra("IMAGE", alphabets[holder.adapterPosition].image)
        intent.putExtra("SOUND", alphabets[holder.adapterPosition].sound)*/
        parent.context.startActivity(intent)
    }
    return ViewHolder(view)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int = alphabets.size


override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ItemAlphabetAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {

    val alphabet = alphabets[position]
    holder.name.text = alphabet.name
    holder.image.visibility = alphabet.image
}

class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    val image: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.alphabet_image)
    val name: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.alphabet_name)

}

}
```

Comment: check size of you arraylist

Comment: Lists and Arrays can not have a size less than 0, thus -1 one is out of bounds and the JVM throws the exception.
I am guessing (without the stack trace) that the issue is in the `onBindViewHolder `method.

Comment: call `itemView.setOnClickListener(this)` inside your custom `ViewHolder`

Comment: try moving your setOnClickListener in onBindViewHolder method using the position: Int of this method instead of holder.position

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to write the following code

```
val intent = Intent(parent.context, ItemAlphabetDetailActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("NAME", alphabets[holder.position].context)/*
        intent.putExtra("CONTEXT", alphabets[holder.adapterPosition].context)
        intent.putExtra("IMAGE", alphabets[holder.adapterPosition].image)
        intent.putExtra("SOUND", alphabets[holder.adapterPosition].sound)*/
        parent.context.startActivity(intent)
```

in onBindViewHolder() which already gives you position as one of the parameters

Comment: have you read `onBindViewHolder` docs: *"Note that unlike ListView, RecyclerView will not call this method again if the position of the item changes in the data set unless the item itself is invalidated or the new position cannot be determined. For this reason, you should only use the position parameter while acquiring the related data item inside this method and should not keep a copy of it. If you need the position of an item later on (e.g. in a **click listener**), use getAdapterPosition() which will have the updated adapter position."*?

Comment: Problem im my `onCreateViewHolder`, i must return  `holder`, not `ViewHolder(view)`

Comment: @Bekzhan did you see what i wrote in my comment above: `"call itemView.setOnClickListener(this) inside your custom ViewHolder"`?

Answer (score 0):

onCreateViewHolder method is not called everytime the recyclerview needs to display a row but only when a new view needs to be created and there are not enough views on the screen. Instead, onBindViewHolder method is called for each position. So, to have the exact position of the row use `holder.adapterPosition`.

Answer (score 0):

Try This. Move your setOnClickListener in onBindViewHolder

itemView.setOnClickListener {
     if(position!=-1){

```
    val intentIntent(itemView.context,ItemAlphabetDetailActivity::class.java)
    intent.putExtra("NAME", alphabets[position].context)/*
    intent.putExtra("CONTEXT", alphabets[position].context)
    intent.putExtra("IMAGE", alphabets[position].image)
    intent.putExtra("SOUND", alphabets[position].sound)*/
    parent.context.startActivity(intent)
}}
```